# Want to requery a url and get fresh value which is assigned to a variable in php every few seconds

Tags: php, ajax, url, auto-update

I have a query which I make to get live prices.. and the value is assigned to a variable.... I want to refresh that query say every 5 seconds and automatically assign the returned value to the variable... so if the variable is called by repeatedly I get new values... in PHP

$requestUrl = http://mmm.com?c=sss;

returns me a value.. which I assign to $price

so when I call $price say every 5 sec it should return fresh values...

Meaning the request url should be run say every 5 sec and values assigned every 5 sec...

Pls guide...

Comment: use setTimeInterval() or can setTimeOut()

Comment: This may be useful for you, http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?169337-Auto-refresh-lt-DIV-gt-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this post which is an excellent guide on how to achieve this - 
[How to Refresh/Reload Page or Part of the Page Automatically](http://www.techtricky.com/how-to-refresh-page-or-part-of-the-page-automatically/).  It show a full meta refresh using specified time or a partial refresh. Another good example on how to do this - 
[Auto refresh webpage every 5 second with PHP,HTML and JavaScript](http://rajeshstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/02/auto-refresh-webpage-reload-every-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, something like this will do,

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>               
            $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#myDiv").load("mypage.php");
                 var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                 $("#myDiv").load("http://mmm.com?c=sss");
                 }, 5000);
                 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
              });
          </script>
        </head>
      <body>

     <div id="myDiv"></div>
     </body>
```